# Uploading to the Arduino Error

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to upload the blink code to Arduino but I'm getting this error.
Could someone help me?

```
  Arduino: 1.6.9 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Duemilanove or Diecimila, ATmega328"

Sketch uses 1,066 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30,720 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x04
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfc
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x8a
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x88

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x14

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_initialize(): (b) protocol error, expect=0x10, resp=0x01
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude: stk500_disable(): protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x10
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

-This is the code I'm trying to upload. Its straight off the Arduino example.

```
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code snippet which triggers this error too.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your arduino code (it has not ever reached the arduino). Look for things like a bad cable, incorrect port selected, reset the arduino, close serial monitor, unplug/re-plug usb cable, etc.

Comment: Is the board really a Duemilanove or Diecimila?  If not, change the IDE setting under Tools | Board to the correct board.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing you can really do with "avrdude", but you can change your type to "AVR ISP":
[image]